# Error con la función DATEDIFF en Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
SELECT nacimiento, DATEDIFF(YEAR, nacimiento, GETDATE()) as Edad FROM mascotas
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

¿Está correcta la sintaxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando sintaxis de SQL Server en MySQL. Ambos son productos distintos con sintaxis distinta aunque sea similar.

Lo que necesitas es usar las funciones correctas.

```
SELECT nacimiento,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,nacimiento,CURDATE()) AS Edad
FROM mascotas;
```

Comment: Me sirvió, gracias!

Comment: Si te sirvió, es útil que marques la respuesta como "aceptada" para que otros usuarios puedan identificarla más fácil.