# DATEDIFF de SQLSERVER en POSTGRESQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Hola colegas estoy intentando llevar la funcion datediff de sqlserver a postgresql con date_part pero no logro hacer que funcione, es para un filtro de busqueda

sqlserver

```
 OR LOWER(CAST(
        "DATEDIFF(month, USER.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION, AGENTE.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO)" as text))
```

postgresql(lo que estoy intentando)

```
OR LOWER(CAST(
        DATE_PART('month', "USER"."USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION" :: date) 
        - 
        DATE_PART('month', "AGENTE"."AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO" :: date) as text))
```

Gracias

Comment: Has vito esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389834/error-con-la-funci%c3%b3n-datediff-en-sql?

Comment: vi algo similar con extract() pero no lo supe implementar, me he estado guiando por este enlace http://sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar esa misma idea de la funcion `DATE_PART` pero pero con algunos ajustes, por ejemplo, si quieres la diferencia de meses debes hacer un cálculo con los años:

```
SELECT (DATE_PART('year', now()::date) - DATE_PART('year', '2019-01-01'::date))*12 + DATE_PART('month', now()::date) - DATE_PART('month', '2019-01-01'::date)
```

con los campos de tu tabla:

```
SELECT (DATE_PART('year', AGENTE.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO::date) - DATE_PART('year', USER.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION::date))*12 + DATE_PART('month', AGENTE.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO::date) - DATE_PART('month', USER.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION::date)
```

Comment: Vi unos ejemplos al respecto, pero no supe llevar la consulta a ello, se supone que en donde van las fechas '2019-01-01' debieran ir los campos de las tablas?

Comment: si deben ir ahi tus campos de las tablas, a continuacion te coloco una posibe solucion a tu caso